# Архитектура flutter приложение

Tags: архитектура, flutter, dart

Только изучаю flutter и ищу информацию об архитектуре приложения. Больше всего меня интересует имеется ли такая практика как в c# разделить слои на под проекты, если да то как это реализовать или где можно подробно почитать. На данный момент я нашел только то, что обычно проект делят на 3 слоя : Data, Domain и Presentation, но в примерах эти слои не делятся на проекты. Так же интересует как лучше всего использовать внедрение зависимостей при таком подходе.